# Cannot use object of type stdClass... Google Search api extracting urls to an array

Tags: php, arrays, object, google-search-api, stdclass

NON-WORKING Code:

**Notice: Trying to get property of non-object**

```
$i = 1;
var_dump($rez->responseData->results[$i]->url);
```

**Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in**

```
$rez = (array) $rez;
var_dump($rez['responseData']['results']['1']['url']);
```

RESULTS of WORKING Code:
**How do I extact only urls and turn url list into an array?**

```
stdClass Object
(
[responseData] => stdClass Object
    (
        [results] => Array
            (
                [0] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [GsearchResultClass] => GwebSearch
                        [unescapedUrl] => http://www.rottentomatoes.com/top/
                        [url] => http://www.rottentomatoes.com/top/
                        [visibleUrl] => www.rottentomatoes.com
...........................................................................
```

WORKING Code:

```
function google_search_api($args, $referer = 'http://localhost/test/', $endpoint = 'web'){
$url = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/".$endpoint;

if ( !array_key_exists('v', $args) )
    $args['v'] = '1.0';

$url .= '?'.http_build_query($args, '', '&');

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
// note that the referer *must* be set
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $referer);
$body = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
//decode and return the response
return json_decode($body);
}

$rez = google_search_api(array(
    'q' => 'movie list', 'start' => '5',
 ));

echo '<pre>';
print_r($rez);
echo '</pre>';
?>
```

I have tried multiple variations of the above but just am not figuring it out. Probably something simple so any comment would be appreciated.

Comment: Might just be your example but your `results` array only has one item at index 0 yet you're trying to dump index 1. Looks like more of a job for a loop anyway

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like this should work

```
$urls = array_map(function($result) {
    return $result->url;
}, $rez->responseData->results);
```